# Creating charts with Netzke

Tags: extjs, netzke

Does anyone knows the way to create ext js charts with Netzke? I guess there is no such component right know, but maybe someone have an idea. 
What are the basic steps to connect using Rails and EXT JS, without Netzke?

Answer (score 1):

I have looked at that gist and this https://gist.github.com/1190511
But I still can't figure it out. Is there a chance to see, no matter how simple a working version of the simplest chart in the Demo app or anything else? I understand the EXT side but I am having a real problem in putting it together with Netzke. I know I am missing something really simple.

Comment: I'll add something like this to Netzke demo after the release of 0-8.

Answer (score 0):

A chart component is too application-specific, but it's surely possible to create one using Netzke built-in client-server mechanisms. Here's a demo: http://variant.herokuapp.com (try selecting different dates on the calendar to see the charts updated on the fly). Here's a gist for the LineChart component used there: https://gist.github.com/4112061 - hope, it can give you an idea (Netzke 0.7.x).

Comment: The gist fails to cover data format. Is there a working chart example for '~> netzke 0.8.x'?  Even a simple one will be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: What exact functionality would you like to achieve? Like, reloading the chart from the server on a request?